# Calculate time left with this?

Tags: php, time, strtotime, calc

I wrote out a script to change user's key active status to 0 if there time is up. When starting there time I set `start_time` to time(); than set how many days like "60".

How could I calculate the time left in day's or hours or minutes left based on my current way of doing this.

```
$user_info['days'] = "60"

`start_time` = 1332219600


function setup() {
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'stresser_main', 'ZLLAUkuLIUU');
    mysql_select_db('stresser_main');
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `active`='1'");
    while ($user_info = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $time_ago = strtotime("-" . $user_info['days'] . " day");
        $time_ago_other = strtotime("+" . $user_info['days'] . " day");
        mysql_query("UPDATE `keys` SET `active`='0' WHERE `start_time` < $time_ago AND `id`='" . $user_info['id'] . "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: `strtotime();` can take two parameters, the second is a timestamp, that is the starting point (it will default to now) so if you do `strtotime("+60 days", 1332219600);` it will tell you the timestamp of the expiry

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't do such think. Do only update query. If you have 1000 users with active = 1 that are expired then you will do 1000 update queries. This way you will do 1 query that will solve your problem. No select and while is needed.

   `mysql_query("UPDATE keys SET active = 0 WHERE active = 1 AND start_time < $something");`
2. Do everything on the SQL like `'WHERE start_time < NOW()'`. You can also do the calculations on the sql. Here you have alot of SQL functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
   This will be much faster and much safer.
3. Don't use mysql_ functions. Use mysqli_ or PDO.
4. Use datetime fields on table, not integer unix timestamp. You will be able to use SQL date functions.
5. Use \DateTime() instead of strtotime.

Comment: PDO Imo is annoying, mysqli does not offer as many functions and mysql is fine.

Comment: Now using mysqli :) first time using it; and I really like it.

Comment: PDO annoying? mysqli have less functions then mysql? I suggest you to try OOP and read about sql injections.
Also read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
mysql_ is officially deprecated. No more support to it.

I gave you 5 points to think about. Hope it will help. If yes, rate.